# Re-render a sibling component using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and I'm trying to get the one component to re-render from another component.

Here's my code:

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child1 />
            <Child2 />
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I intend to do is update Child1 when there is some trigger from Child2.

One way I can think of is to get the parent component to re-render so both Child1 and Child2 will be updated. I tried to do this by lifting the state but it doesn't seem to re-render each of the child components. Here's the code

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const handlePost = (newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Child1 />
            <Child2 onPost={handlePost} />
        </div>
    )
}

const Child2 = (props) => {
    // This function is executed when there is a trigger. 
    // In this case, when a post request is made to the server
    const onPost() => {
        props.handlePost('new value')
    }
}
```

Edit:
The reason why the component(s) needs to be re-rendered is because they are making changes to the API and these changes need to be reflected on the screen. It has nothing to do with any state variables.

Comment: @ggorlen How else can I check if the value is actually getting changed? The component is not getting re-rendered. I was accessing `value` just to check if it's not a scope issue but it seems like it isn't.

Comment: @ggorlen Oh I see, seems like the value in fact is getting change but the child components are not getting re-rendered. Sorry, I wasn't able to explain before but my intention is to re-render the Notes component.

Comment: @ggorlen since I made a post request to the server, there is a new note added in the database and i wanted to add that to the screen. The Notes component makes a get request when it mounts so I thought re-rendering it would be a good option. If there is a better way to get it done please do let me know.

Comment: @ggorlen I changed the question and I hope this is more understandable compared to the original

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't really reproduce the problem with this code. Each child renders twice as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ggorlen The line `props.handlePost('new value')` is only executed when there is a trigger (POST request in this case). However, `Child1` should be making  a get request again since it is re-rendered which it somehow doesnt. The code to make the get request for Child2 is something like `useEffect(makeRequest, []`.

Comment: @JonasWilms It is because there are some changes in the database made by `Child2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is an XY problem. In the example given it does not make sense that Child1 rerenders cause there is no need for it. From the comments your *real problem* is that you update one API, which is supposed to change the response of another API. If you however already know how the response will change, and that it will change, this can be reflected in *one state* that changes for both API calls:

```
 function useEntries() {
   const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      setEntries(getEntries());
   }, []);

   function addEntry(entry) {
     postEntry(entry);
    setEntries(prev => [...prev, entry]);
   }

   return { entries, addEntry };
 }

 function Parent() {
   const { entries, addEntry } = useEntries();

   return <>
     <Entries entries={entries} />
     <AddEntry addEntry={addEntry} />
   </>;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is a great approach.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in the post, it sounds like you have `Child1` presenting results of a `GET` request (being done in `Child1`). `Child2` can add or modify that state on the server with some kind of request and you want to trigger a re-render in order to make `Child1` refresh the state.

The general problem is, that children should only re-render if props or their used contexts change. I see two options how to approach this:

1. Lift the handling of the requests up into the parent. Put the results of the request as props into the child component you want to refresh.
2. Make the sibling aware of the request having to reload by setting it to "dirty" in some way. Either through context or routing state around through the parent.

Usually it's best to go with option 1 if the components are not too deeply nested. It could look like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const fetchNewestPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    const fetched = await fetchPosts();
    setPosts(fetched);
  }, [fetchPosts, setPosts]);
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (event) => {
    const newPost = getValuesFromSubmitEvent(event);
    await sendNewPost(newPost);
    // you could even set the posts here to what you think the 
    // send request will result in (see Jonas Wilms answer), like
    // setPosts(posts => [newPost, ...posts]);
    await fetchNewestPosts();
  }, [fetchNewestPosts, getValuesFromSubmitEvent, sendNewPost]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNewestPosts();
  }, [fetchNewestPosts]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Child1 posts={posts} />
      <Child2 submitNewPost={submitNewPost} />
    </div>
  );
);

const Child1 = ({posts}) => {
  return (
    <ul>{posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>post.title</li>)}</ul>
  );
);

const Child2 = ({submitNewPost}) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitNewPost}>...</form>
  );
);
```

As a nice side-effect, `Child1` and `Child2` now need a lot less logic and can be styled independently of the `fetchPosts` and `sendNewPost` functions.

Comment: I really shouldn't write too many options into my answers as both options were independently added as answers while I was writing this... 

Comment: @Narigo Thank you. I really appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, lets say that Child1 must be re-rendered on `handlePost`. Your parent component will be:

```
const Parent= () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
const [rerender, setrerender] = useState(false)

const handlePost = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    let setrerender_temp = rerender;
    setrerender(!setrerender_temp);
}

return (
    <div>
        <Child1 rerender={rerender} />
        <Child2 onPost={handlePost} />
    </div>
)
}
```

Then, in your Child1 component:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
...

export default function Child1(props) {
   const [,forceRender] = useReducer((s) => s+1, 0);
   useEffect(() => forceRender(), [props.rerender]);
   ...
}
```

Comment: the reducer and the effect inside Child are completely useless.

Comment: Ciao @JonasWilms, I try to explain you: useEffect is the hook I use to listen when props.rerender changes from Parent. useReducer is used to force the re-render of Child1 component (calling forceRender()). Something is unclear?

Comment: `Child1` should re-render because `props.rerender` is changed, not because of the `forceRender` call. In this example `Child1` is going to re-render twice, if I'm not mistaken. If you replace `forceRender()` with the actual fetch call, it should suffice as a solution though.

Comment: Ciao, "Child1 should re-render because props.rerender is changed, not because of the forceRender call" yeah you're right: Child1 will re-rendered (calling forceRender()) because props.rerender is changed. Why you say that Child1 will be re-rendered twice?